# Port forward from OpenShift via Java

Tags: java, openshift

How to programmatically execute

```
oc port-forward <podName> <podPort>:<localPort>
```

via Java?
At the moment I managed to get the list of pods under through the library io.fabric8:openshift-client.

```
OpenShiftClient config = new DefaultOpenShiftClient();
client.pods().inNamespace("namespace").list().getItems();
```

But in this library don't exist port-forwarding functionality and I didn't find any information on the net

Comment: I found this example in the source code for the library: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/02826311061aa15633f7482397ae3ce11e26d34e/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/kubectl/equivalents/PortForwardEquivalent.java  Note that the `oc` command is an extension of `kubectl`. Similarly, `OpenShiftClient` extends `KubernetesClient`

Comment: why cant you use routes or published service?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works like a charm :

```
OpenShiftClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build().adapt(OpenShiftClient.class);

Resource<Namespace> openShiftProject = client.namespaces().withName(yourNamespace);

PodResource openShiftPod = client.pods().inNamespace(yourNamespace).withName(yourPodName);

openShiftPod.portForward(REMOTE_PORT_NBR, LOCAL_PORT_NBR);
```

Feel free to add some checks (`isReady` for instance) to secure your code.  And don't forget to close the client once its job is over.